# Yii2 elasticsearch setAttributes() not working

Tags: php, elasticsearch, yii2

I am using Yii 2.1 and Yii2-elasticsearch 2.0.3 with a elasticsearch 1.5.0 server to try and index a Member model for a more powerful search. I have a `common\indexes\Member` model that extends `yii\elasticsearch\ActiveRecord` and set up the attributes I want to index.

```
namespace common\indexes;

use yii\elasticsearch\ActiveRecord;

class Member extends ActiveRecord {

    /**
     * @return array the list of attributes for this record
     */
    public function attributes() {
        // path mapping for '_id' is setup to field 'id'
        return ['id', 'given_name', 'family_name', 'email'];
    }
}
```

I am having trouble setting the attributes I want in the `common\indexes\Member` model.

I am creating a new instance of the object and trying to set the attribute values via the ActiveRecord setAttributes() method but it doesn't seem to set any values.

```
$index = new common\indexes\Member();
$index->setAttributes(['given_name' => 'Test', 'family_name' => 'User', 'email' => 'test.member@test.com']);
$index->save();
```

This seems to create an empty record. If I manually set the attributes one by one everything seems to work and a record with the correct attributes is created in the elasticsearch database.

```
$index = new common\indexes\Member();
$index->given_name = 'Test';
$index->family_name = 'User';
$index->email = 'test.member@test.com';
$index->save();
```

Am I using the `setAttributes()` method incorrectly for elasticsearch ActiveRecord's? Do I need to set up my elasticsearch Model differently?

Comment: Is it a typo in your code that you actually defined from `AbstractIndex` instead of `elasticsearch\ActiveRecord` as you claim?

Comment: Yes, that is a typo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default `setAttributes` only sets attributes that have at least a single validation rule defined or those that are - as a minimum - defined as being "safe" (either via [`safeAttributes()`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-base-model.html#safeAttributes()-detail) or via the safe-validator).

You can force it to assign everything by just changing the call to

```
$index->setAttributes([
   'given_name' => 'Test', 
   'family_name' => 'User', 
   'email' => 'test.member@test.com'
], false);
```

This tells it it is okay to also assign non-safe attributes.
But I usually prefer to make sure [the validation](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-base-model.html#rules()-detail) is configured correctly

Comment: Also adding the rules() method with the safe attributes worked. public function rules() { return [ [['email', 'given_name', 'family_name'], 'safe'] ];}

Comment: That would be the correct way to do it indeed. Now that you have validation rules, perhaps make them as they really should be? ie if they are required: use `"required"` (all `Validators` imply `safe`).